# How to prevent JPA saves during database upgrade?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I would like to upgrade my database. It will cause downtime. So I would like to disable JPA saves temporarily using a feature flag. How can I enforce prevention of saves e.g. throw DataIntegrityViolationException whenever code makes it to a save.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how you expect to continue performing reads during your upgrade, either.  One would ordinarily take the whole application down during such a maintenance operation.

Comment: It's not easy to do with JPA, but you can change the database user's grant to insert, update and delete rows. If you are using JDBC, most database also accept a readonly parameter to prevent alterations.

Comment: You could also revoke data modification privileges from the user the application authenticates with. However changing the application to not go wild when intended db modifications are requested is the bigger task.

Comment: https://github.com/alexandre-touret/maintenance-mode   `I_AM_A_TEAPOT` LOL

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think I was thinking I could use read replicas to keep allowing reads whilst preventing writes

Answer (score 0):

Not on the application side, but on the database side, you can put a lock on your databases so that the current operations end, but there are no new operations.
https://docs.postgresql.fr/15/sql-lock.html

To automate this, you can look at the pg_catalog to list the tables to lock